# How to catch ReactiveCommand Exceptions?

Tags: c#, exception, reactiveui

I have a basic `ReactiveCommand`. No async wizardry, just plain old `ReactiveCommand.Create()`. I `Subscribe()` with the overload that takes an exception handler, but never hit the breakpoint in said exception handler (I did not expect this). I subscribe to `ThrownErrors`, never hit the breakpoint in that exception handler either (I sort of expected this).

Here's the example code:

```
var myCommand = ReactiveCommand.Create();

// this does not seem to work
myCommand.Subscribe(
    _ => { throw new Exception("oops"); },
    ex => { 
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Mesage);
            Debugger.Break(); 
          });

//this does not seem to work either
myCommand.ThrownExceptions.Subscribe(
    ex => { 
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Mesage);
            Debugger.Break();
          });
```

I did my homework and checked the questions and answers in the topic.

[ReactiveUI exception handling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13949710/reactiveui-exception-handling)

[How to catch exception from ReactiveCommand?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32987488/how-to-catch-exception-from-reactivecommand)

I have checked the mail list as well, and found this:
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/reactivexaml/Dkc-cSesKPY

So I decided to change this to some async solution:

```
var myCommand = ReactiveCommand.CreateAsyncObservable(_ => this.Throw());
myCommand.Subscribe(
    _ => { Console.WriteLine("How did we get here?"); },
    // this is not expected to work
    ex => { 
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            Debugger.Break();
          });

// however, I sort of expect this to work
myCommand.ThrownExceptions.Subscribe(
    ex => {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            Debugger.Break();
          });

[...]

private IObservable<object> Throw()
{
    Debugger.Break();
    throw new Exception("oops");
}
```

And yet, I never hit any of my breakpoints, except the one in the `Throw()` method. :(

What am I doing wrong? How am I supposed to catch exceptions here?

**Edit**:

I do, however, hit the exception handler breakpoint when I throw the exception from within the observable, like this

```
private IObservable<object> Throw()
{
    Debugger.Break();
    return Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
            {
                throw new Exception("oops");
                return new object();
            }).ToObservable();
}
```

Question modified to: "am I capable of handling an exception from within the method and not the observable?"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bug in the current release of ReactiveUI - the exception thrown while creating the 'execute' observable is swallowed and the internal state of the `ReactiveCommand` is left in a broken state.  This has been fixed in the next release.

See [this github issue](https://github.com/reactiveui/ReactiveUI/issues/973) for details.